# How to set explode transition with xml file

Tags: android, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm trying to `setEnterTransition` with explode.xml file.

i tried this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionManager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <transition android:transition="@transition/explode" />
</transitionManager>
```

and this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <explode
            android:duration="500"
            android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/bounce" />
 </transitionSet>
```

but explode animation did not work, any ideas?

Comment: How's you using this `xml` in your code ?

Comment: i'm using it in my style  <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@transition/explode</item>

Comment: You have to create a `WindowAnimationTransition` style in  your `style.xml`(with `android:windowEnterAnimation` and `android:windowExitAnimation`). Then use this style as `windowAnimationStyle`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Firstly, create a Transition XML for explode transition named `explode.xml` in `res/transition` folder. As,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <explode
        android:duration="320" />
</transitionSet>
```

Then, in `styles.xml` in your `AppTheme` set `android:windowContentTransitions` as true and reference the `explode` transition for **Enter** and **Exit** like below:

```
<item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
<item name="android:windowEnterTransition">@transition/explode</item>
<item name="android:windowExitTransition">@transition/explode</item>
```

Now start your activity as,

```
ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivitiy.class);
startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

Comment: getting error Unknown animation name: transitionManager, i think my xml code is not correct, can you provide correct explode xml file

Comment: @HeisenBrg, i would like to ask few questions here

1) in ActivityOptions or anywhere else , we haven't wrote any piece of code that reflects that we are using that particular explode transition , How android knows we want to use that transition .

2)If we make more transitions in the transitions folder how can we specify which transition would happen for which activity ?

3)Can we make transition between activities just by using Explode explode = new Explode() in java ?
if so how can we accomplish that.

i would be thankful for the answers .

Comment: @SyedHissaan I will give you the explanation for all your question. But first, I want to know that is this piece of code working for you or not?

Comment: @HeisenBrg, thanks for courtesy , this piece of code is working for me,

Comment: @HeisenBrg can i have your explanation .